# How do I assign a field value as an alias name for an index in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, alias

This is a far as I have gotten (even though it still wouldnt solve my problem since I would have to and the filter term manually). I would like to divide the index into alias indices based on the different casenumbers...How do I modify the code below to accomplish this with variables so it loops through and does it automatically?

```
POST /_aliases?pretty
{
 "actions": [
   {
     "add": {
       "index": "job_name_new",
       "alias": "20-41308",
       "filter": {
         "term": {
           "casenumber.keyword": "20-41308"
         }
       }
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

I have tried the following and gotten nowhere:

```
POST /_aliases?pretty
{
 "actions": [
   {
     "add": {
       "index": "job_name_new",
       "alias": "_source":["casenumber"]",
       "filter": {
         "term": {
           "casenumber.keyword": "20-41308"
         }
       }
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

Comment: It's not possible, you have to do it manually

Comment: i'm not sure about the benefit: you're already manually setting `20-41308` in your filter.term, at that point, why not also in the alias field? You can easily script these calls anyhow: given an array of values, it'll be trivial to iterate over the array to generate your _aliases calls

Comment: My goal was to assign an alias from the case number and just figured I would restrict it to that one in the beginning to test it. I ended up instead using an ingest pipeline script and created separate indices altogether instead of aliases...ctx._index=ctx.casenumber

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it with a script:

```
[
  {
    "script": {
      "source": ctx._index = Arrays.asList(ctx.path.virtual.splitOnToken('/'))[1];",
      "lang": "painless"
    }
  }
]
```